# How apple store determine languages information an application

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my app to apple store.
Everything is fine except the "Languages" in "Details" tab.
I don't know why many languages in my app's information. (see below picture).

1. is this setting in ituneconnect ? (I have only one localize in
   ituneconnect)
2. or somewhere in xcode ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a library that includes localizations from certain languages, those languages will appear there as well, even though your entire app doesn't use those languages. Look for localization folders (.lproj) with strings files in them. This has happened to me in the past.

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated my app by deleting unused localize folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is based on the `Localizations` section in your **Project** Info tab

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My project Info tab has only one language. I find that one of my library included localizations, so it may be cause of this problem.